# VSTS: Feed package version variable as dropdown when performing a release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When we perform a release, we need to select specific package versions to deploy (latest by default, but it could be older versions as well). Right now that field is a simple text box where we have to manually specify the version, but this is error prone since the user can basically put whatever they want there and requires us to update the release definition whenever a new version is pushed to the feed. Is there some way to configure the variable in the definition to look at the specific versions of a package in a feed and display that as a dropdown to the user?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this by default. You need to create a custom build task and call the Feed API to achieve that.

For example, add following section in your custom build task:

```
"inputs": [
        {
          "name": "feedList",
          "type": "pickList",
          "label": "feedList",
          "defaultValue": "",
          "required": false,
          "helpMarkDown": "Select the feed.",
          "properties": {
                    "DisableManageLink": "True"
                }   
        },
        {
          "name": "packageList",
          "type": "pickList",
          "label": "packageList",
          "defaultValue": "",
          "required": false,
          "helpMarkDown": "Select the package.",
          "properties": {
                    "DisableManageLink": "True"
                }   
        },
        {
            "name": "versionList",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "versionList",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": false,
            "helpMarkDown": "Select the version.",
            "properties": {
                      "DisableManageLink": "True"
                  }   
          }
      ],
      "dataSourceBindings": [
            {
                "target": "feedList",
                "endpointId": "tfs:feed",
                "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/packaging/feeds",
                "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
                "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
            },
            {
                "target": "packageList",
                "endpointId": "tfs:feed",
                "parameters": {
                    "feed": "$(feedList)"
                },
                "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{{{feed}}}/Packages",
                "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
                "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
            },
            {
                "target": "versionList",
                "endpointId": "tfs:feed",
                "parameters": {
                    "feed": "$(feedList)",
                    "package": "$(packageList)"
                },
                "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{{{feed}}}/Packages/{{{package}}}/Versions",
                "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
                "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{version}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{version}}}\" }"
            }
        ],
```

You will get a list to select the package version:
[image]
And then you can get the selected version and set the variable value to the selected one in the customer build task.

Comment: Not sure how a custom build task solves the problem. Can you provide an example or at least further explanation?

Comment: @fepiv I updated my answer, please refer to it for details.